# No logro acceder a los metodos de mis clases publicas

Tags: c#, webservice

soy nuevo en esto. Inicié una practica de consola completa, con clases, instancias, herencias, acceso a BBDD y webservices.

Al principio bien, pero de golpe, desde mi classe principal program no puedo ver mi metodo de accesos a WebServices y no logro entender porque.

Esta es la classe/Metodo que llama al WebServices

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el programa principal, donde quiero llamar al metodo GetPost.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el caso que se muestra, estoy intentando llamar al metodo de dos manera distintas, la primera me da error CS0176 y la segunda CS0029.  He probado otras cosas pero tampoco me funcionan.

Por favor necesito ayuda.
Gracias

Comment: ¿Has visto qué dice el error?

Comment: el error CS0029 es un error que denota que no se puede convertir de un tipo a otro, por ejemplo de tipo int a string, etc, lo que indica que tu esperas un  List<Posts> pero el metodo GetPost no retorna ese mismo tipo. Puedes intentar simplemente asignando con var post = WebServices.GetPost(), para el otro error lo mas probable es que tu metodo GetPost() sea estatico, y lo estas queriendo llamar por medio de una instancia.

Comment: varias cosas, lo primero: bienvenido!, lo segundo: como tienes las clases `WebServices` y `Posts` ? GetPost es un método público? o es estático (`static`)? te recomiendo que realices el [tour] y leas [ask], las imágenes de código no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que no todos tienen un buen internet, las tienen capadas, son daltónicos, no pueden copiar y pegar... es mejor y mas fácil que copies y pegues el código,

Comment: Gracias por los consejos.  Añado una respuesta que encontré siguiendo lo que entiendo que son los metodos de comentar aquí.  Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

He avanzado un poco.

El metodo tenia esta definición.  **static async Task<List>  GetPost()**

La primera llamada la intentaba a partir de un objeto y asi no se puede llamar un metodo static.

La segunda es correct a para llamar un metodo static pero devuelve un Task<List>  y no permite asignarlo a un <List. Yo necesito recuperar un <List.

Asi pues he hecho lo siguiente:

```
 1 - He cambiado la definicion del metodo GetPost a **static async Task  GetPost()**, asi que ahora no devuelve nada.

 2 - He creado un objeto List<Posts> privado dentro de la clase webservices y he hecho que el metodo GetPost lo informe al final.

 3 - Y por ultimo he creado un metodo publico GetPostP que ejecuta el GetPost(); y devuelve el objeto List<Posts>.
```

Aqui pongo el codigo de ambas classes

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        WebServices ws = new WebServices();
        List<Posts> posts = new List<Posts>();
        posts = ws.GestPostP();
        //var y = WebServices.GetPost();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}



class WebServices
{
    private static List<Posts> posts = new List<Posts>();
    public List<Posts> GestPostP() 
    {
        GetPost();
        return posts;
    }

    static async Task GetPost()
    {
        string urlWS = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
        //List<Posts> post = new List<Posts>();
        try
        {
            using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            {
                var res = await client.GetAsync(urlWS);
                if (res != null)
                {
                    var content = await 
                               res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    posts = 
                      JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Posts>>(content);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw; }            
    }
}
```

Sin  embargo ahora tengo un nuevo problema. Cuando el programa de consola llama al webservices este termina bruscamente con el mensaje

```
terminó con código 0 (0x0).
```

Esto me paso anteriomente y lo resolve en opciones desactivando **Mensajes de salida de subprocesos**. Pero ahora vuelve a suceder y no se que puede ser.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código 0 indica que no hubo error, es probable que sea porque que debido a que tienes en asincrónico el getPost no se espera a que se complete y encuentras la lista vacía, ya que aún no ha terminado. prueba `  GetPost().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); `  aunque ahora se convertirá en sincrónico para ver si es el caso

Comment: Es correcto. Gracias.

El problema es que estaba llamando un mentodo asincrono desde otro que no y perdia el hilo de ejecución. Finalmente he tenido que poner todo del Main para abajo Asincrono y statico y me funcion correctamente.